# can not load rxbag_plugins correctly

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I am trying to plot my trajectory topic in a decent way. rxbag_plugins plot seems like a very promising tool to plot the trajectory topic. But while run rxbag, I got the following error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong at here? thanks. By the way, I am using fuerte on ubuntu 12.04. thanks.

```
Unable to load plugin [rxbag_plugins.plugins] from package [rxbag_plugins]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rxbag/plugins.py", line 70, in load_plugins
    roslib.load_manifest(pkg)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 98, in _generate_python_path
    packages = get_depends(pkg, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 51, in get_depends
    vals = rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 195, in get_depends
    names = [p.name for p in self.get_manifest(name).depends]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/me/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/home/me/test
ROS path [3]=/home/me/hg_repo_cambridge
ROS path [4]=/home/me/ros_pkg/rxbag_plugin/rxbag_plugins/src/rxbag_plugins
ROS path [5]=/home/me/ros_pkg
ROS path [6]=/opt/me/fuerte/share
ROS path [7]=/opt/me/fuerte/stacks

Unable to load plugin [tf2_visualization.rxbag_plugin] from package [tf2_visualization]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rxbag/plugins.py", line 70, in load_plugins
    roslib.load_manifest(pkg)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 98, in _generate_python_path
    packages = get_depends(pkg, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 51, in get_depends
    vals = rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 195, in get_depends
    names = [p.name for p in self.get_manifest(name).depends]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/me/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/home/me/test
ROS path [3]=/home/me/hg_repo_cambridge
ROS path [4]=/home/me/ros_pkg/rxbag_plugin/rxbag_plugins/src/rxbag_plugins
ROS path [5]=/home/me/ros_pkg
ROS path [6]=/opt/me/fuerte/share
ROS path [7]=/opt/me/fuerte/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62425/can-not-load-rxbag_plugins-correctly/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ResourceNotFound: catkin
```

You need to install `catkin`.

Also, why not consider using [rqt_bag](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_bag) that succeeds `rxbag` from ROS `Groovy` but is availbale in `Fuerte` too?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0